# How long can I stay in Singapore on a multiple entry pass visa?

Tags: visas, work, singapore, multiple-entry

I am trying to get a Singapore multiple entry visa. My question is: can I work in Singapore on this visa base legally? After how many days do I need to come back to my home-country?

Answer (score 5):

**You won't be able to work on the visa.**

What you need to get in order to legally work in Singapore is some sort of [work pass or permit](http://www.mom.gov.sg/passes-and-permits), which usually your employer will have to get for you. However, there is no issue with looking for a job while on a visa. Once you get a job, your employer can apply for a work permit or pass on your behalf, which will give you a long term pass to stay in the country.

Until then, you will most probably not be able to stay [any longer than 30 days](http://www.globalsingapore.sg/visa-to-singapore/singapore-visa-faq/) at a time in Singapore.

DO NOT [overstay](http://www.straitstimes.com/news/singapore/courts-crime/story/45-foreign-nationals-arrested-overstaying-20150313) or [work illegally](http://www.channelnewsasia.com/news/singapore/illegal-import-of-foreign/299586.html), as this will most certainly get you into trouble, and other than being potentially fined, [caned and/or imprisoned](http://www.todayonline.com/singapore/two-men-jailed-attempting-depart-singapore-illegally-woodlands-checkpoint), you will also be very unlikely to be granted a visa again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple entry visa is a business pass working not allowed on this pass and 1month + 1month extend and one re- enter total...3month

Comment: Do you have any links or sources to back up this statement?

Comment: Also, please write in full sentences. I can't understand what you're saying.